# Getting a picture from firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating an iOS application which has many  pictures on it. I therefore decided to use a database to store the pictures on and retrieve from the database. I have inputted the pictures manually through the Firebase site.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class F_A_1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewer: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let animalref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("animal/bird.png")

    animalref.dataWidthMaxSize(1*1000*1000){ (date, error) in
    if error = nill {
        print(data)
        self.imageViewer.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving me an error which I cannot fix.

Thanks in advance :)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class F_A_1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewer: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let animalref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("animal/bird.png")

    func nameThisWhatYouWant() {
        animalref.data(withMaxSize: 1*1000*1000) { (data, error) in
        if error == nil { 
           print(data)
        } else {
           print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

i have tried this but it gives a sigbart error

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have never worked with Firebase and don't know how to go about connecting it, but you have an issue where you are doing logic in your app.

```
class F_A_1: UIViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     }

    let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let animalref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("animal/bird.png")


    func nameThisWhatYouWant() {
        animalref.dataWidthMaxSize(1*1000*1000){ (date, error) in
            if error = nill {
                print(data)

                self.imageViewer.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            } else{
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a function called **nameThisWhatYouWant** where you should be handling your data, and sending it off to Firebase. As far as working with Firebase, go [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) to see how to set up Firebase by working with Cocoa Pods, then allowing you to import Firebase. As far as actually being able to send your data off, they have tons of documentation and examples to follow to read through.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the error to `nill` instead of `nil`.

Where are you getting your error?